Audio Module Not Enabled Error in Firefox with Zoom Video SDK UI Toolkit
I'm working with the Zoom Video SDK (JavaScript) and specifically using the Video SDK UI Toolkit (following the example from the Zoom SDK UI Toolkit GitHub repository).
Description
I'm encountering an issue with audio in Firefox only. The setup and code work correctly on all other major browsers, but when using Firefox, attempting to start audio fails with an error. The error is reproducible both in my application and on Zoom’s own UI Toolkit Demo site.
Error
When trying to start audio, the following error message appears:
Audio: The operation is invalid, perhaps caused by duplicated operations

And in the console, more details are provided:
start audio error Object { type: "INVALID_OPERATION", reason: "Module:audio is not enabled" }

Troubleshooting Routes

I confirmed that this issue does not occur on other browsers like Chrome or Edge.
I followed the sample application exactly as provided in Zoom’s GitHub repository.
I also tested on the official Zoom UI Toolkit Demo site (videosdk.dev/uitoolkit), and the same issue occurs on Firefox when joining a session with fictional data.

How to Reproduce

Use Firefox (last version or earlier) as the browser. (On windows or MacOs)
Open the Zoom Video SDK UI Toolkit Demo.
Join a session using any fictitious data to authenticate.
Attempt to start audio within the session.
The above error should appear, preventing audio from working as expected.

Thank you for any guidance!
